# Images not lining up in Gmail and outlook

Tags: email, outlook, gmail, html-email, newsletter

Almost at breaking point with this. Coding this in dreamweaver and when I view it in the live mode comes up fine but when in live mode, but when I send it through the email clients such as outlook and gmail, it has one images out of line and i can't see why. New to this so sorry if code is a bit messy.

```
</head>
<body leftmargin="0" marginwidth="0" topmargin="0" marginheight="0" offset="0">
    <center>
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="100%" id="backgroundTable">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top">
                    <!-- // Begin Template Preheader \\ -->
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" width="600" id="templatePreheader">
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top" class="preheaderContent">

                                <!-- // Begin Module: Standard Preheader \ -->
                                <table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td valign="top">
                                            <div mc:edit="std_preheader_content">
                                                 </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <!-- *|IFNOT:ARCHIVE_PAGE|* -->
                                        <td valign="top" width="190">
                                            <div mc:edit="std_preheader_links">
                                                Is this email not displaying correctly?<br /><a href="*|ARCHIVE|*" target="_blank">View it in your browser</a>.
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <!-- *|END:IF|* -->
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                <!-- // End Module: Standard Preheader \ -->

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <!-- // End Template Preheader \\ -->
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" id="templateContainer">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">
                                                                    <!-- // Begin Template Header \\ -->
                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" id="templateHeader">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="padding-top:25px">

                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="headerContent">

                                            <!-- // Begin Module: Standard Header Image \\ -->
                                            <a href="http://www.spaceform.com/"><img src="http://www.spaceform.com/SF/media/site/Newsletters/Email%20Test%20Images/logo1.png" style="max-width:600px; font-family:Tahoma; font-size:32px; color:#000000" alt="Spaceform London" id="headerImage campaign-icon" mc:label="header_image" mc:edit="header_image" mc:allowdesigner mc:allowtext/></a>
                                            <!-- // End Module: Standard Header Image \\ -->

                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="padding-top:10px">

                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="center" style="font-family:Tahoma; font-size:14px; padding-top:15px; padding-bottom:15px">

                                            <a href="http://www.spaceform.com/" style="text-decoration:none; color:#000000">Home</a>&nbsp;&nbsp; |&nbsp; <a href="http://www.spaceform.com/shop" style="text-decoration:none; color:#000000">Shop</a>&nbsp; |&nbsp; <a href="http://www.spaceform.com/shop/bestselling-gifts" style="text-decoration:none; color:#000000">Bestselling Gifts</a>&nbsp; |&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.spaceform.com/shop/personalised-pieces/scripted-pieces" style="text-decoration:none; color:#000000">Personalised Gifts</a>&nbsp; | &nbsp;<a href="http://www.spaceform.com/about-us" style="text-decoration:none; color:#000000">About Spaceform</a>&nbsp; |&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.spaceform.com/contact-us" style="text-decoration:none; color:#000000">Contact us</a></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                <!-- // End Template Header \\ -->
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">
                                <!-- // Begin Template Body \\ -->
                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" id="templateBody">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td valign="top">
                                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td valign="top">
                                                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td valign="top" class="bodyContent">

                                                                    <!-- // Begin Module: Standard Content \\ -->

                                                                        <table border="0" bordercolor="#FFFFFF" style="background-color:#FFFFFF" width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                                                                  <tr> 
                                                                                    <td rowspan="18" width="24" height="1474"><img src="http://www.spaceform.com/SF/media/email/trade/giftideas/cell_02.jpg"  border="0" style="display:block;" width="24" height="1474" /></td>
                                                                                    <td colspan="2" width="552" height="43"><img src="http://www.spaceform.com/SF/media/email/trade/giftideas/cell_03.jpg" border="0" style="display:block;" width="552" height="43" /></td>
                                                                                    <td rowspan="18" width="24" height="1474"><img src="http://www.spaceform.com/SF/media/email/trade/giftideas/cell_04.jpg" border="0" style="display:block;" width="24" height="1474" /></td>
                                                                                  </tr>
                                                                                  <tr>
                                                                                   <td background="http://www.spaceform.com/SF/media/email/trade/giftideas/cell_05.jpg" style="display:block;" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="279" height="122" valign="top">
                                                                                      <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                                                                                      <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:279px;height:122px;">
                                                                                        <v:fill type="tile" src="http://www.spaceform.com/SF/media/email/trade/giftideas/cell_05.jpg" color="#ffffff" />
                                                                                        <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
                                                                                      <![endif]-->
                                                                                      <div>
                                                                                          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</div>
                                                                                      <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                                                                                        </v:textbox>
                                                                                      </v:rect>
                                                                                      <![endif]-->
                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                    <td width="273" height="350" rowspan="3"><img src="http://www.spaceform.com/SF/media/email/trade/giftideas/cell_06.jpg" border="0" style="display:block;" width="273" height="350" /></td>
                                                                                  </tr>
                                                                                  <tr>
                                                                                    <td width="279" height="45"><img src="http://www.spaceform.com/SF/media/email/trade/giftideas/cell_07.jpg" border="0" style="display:block;" width="279" height="45" /></td>
                                                                                  </tr>
                                                                                  <tr>
                                                                                    <td width="279" height="183"><img src="http://www.spaceform.com/SF/media/email/trade/giftideas/cell_08.jpg" border="0" style="display:block;" width="279" height="183" /></td>
                                                                                  </tr>
                                                                                  <tr>
                                                                                    <td colspan="2" width="552" height="41"><img src="http://www.spaceform.com/SF/media/email/trade/giftideas/cell_09.jpg" border="0" style="display:block;" width="552" height="41" /></td>
                                                                                  </tr>
                                                                                  <tr>
                                                                                    <td rowspan="3" width="279" height="233"><img src="http://www.spaceform.com/SF/media/email/trade/giftideas/cell_10.jpg" border="0" style="display:block;" width="279" height="233" /></td>
                                                                                    <td background="http://www.spaceform.com/SF/media/email/trade/giftideas/cell_11.jpg" style="display:block;" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="273" height="93" valign="top">
                                                                                      <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                                                                                      <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:273px;height:93px;">
                                                                                        <v:fill type="tile" src="http://www.spaceform.com/SF/media/email/trade/giftideas/cell_11.jpg" color="#ffffff" />
                                                                                        <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
                                                                                      <![endif]-->
                                                                                      <div>
                                                                                          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</div>
                                                                                      <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                                                                                        </v:textbox>
                                                                                      </v:rect>
                                                                                      <![endif]-->
                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                  </tr>
                                                                                  <tr>
                                                                                    <td width="273" height="37"><img src="http://www.spaceform.com/SF/media/email/trade/giftideas/cell_12.jpg" border="0" style="display:block;" width="273" height="37" /></td>
                                                                                  </tr>
                                                                                  <tr>
                                                                                    <td width="273" height="103"><img src="http://www.spaceform.com/SF/media/email/trade/giftideas/cell_13.jpg" border="0" style="display:block;" width="273" height="103" /></td>
                                                                                  </tr>
                                                                                  <tr>
                                                                                    <td colspan="2" width="552" height="47"><img src="http://www.spaceform.com/SF/media/email/trade/giftideas/cell_14.jpg" border="0" style="display:block;" width="552" height="47" /></td>
                                                                                  </tr>
                                                                                  <tr>
                                                                                    <td rowspan="3" width="279" height="317"><img src="http://www.spaceform.com/SF/media/email/trade/giftideas/cell_15.jpg" border="0" style="display:block;" width="279" height="317" /></td>
                                                                                    <td background="http://www.spaceform.com/SF/media/email/trade/giftideas/cell_16.jpg" style="display:block;" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="273" height="95" valign="top">
                                                                                      <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                                                                                      <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:273px; height:95px">
                                                                                        <v:fill type="tile" src="http://www.spaceform.com/SF/media/email/trade/giftideas/cell_16.jpg" color="#ffffff" />
                                                                                        <v:textbox style="mso-fit-shape-to-text:true" inset="0,0,0,0">
                                                                                      <![endif]-->
                                                                                      <div>
                                                                                          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</div>
                                                                                      <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                                                                                        </v:textbox>
                                                                                      </v:rect>
                                                                                      <![endif]-->
                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                  </tr>
                                                                                  <tr>
                                                                                    <td width="273" height="35"><img src="http://www.spaceform.com/SF/media/email/trade/giftideas/cell_17.jpg" border="0" style="display:block;" width="273" height="35" /></td>
                                                                                  </tr>
                                                                                  <tr>
                                                                                    <td width="273" height="187"><img src="http://www.spaceform.com/SF/media/email/trade/giftideas/cell_18.jpg" border="0" style="display:block;" width="273" height="187" /></td>
                                                                                  </tr>
                                                                                  <tr>
                                                                                    <td colspan="2" width="552" height="41"><img src="http://www.spaceform.com/SF/media/email/trade/giftideas/cell_19.jpg" border="0" style="display:block;" width="552" height="41" /></td>
                                                                                  </tr>
                                                                                  <tr>
                                                                                    <td background="http://www.spaceform.com/SF/media/email/trade/giftideas/cell_20.jpg" style="display:block;" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="279" height="96" valign="top">
                                                                                      <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                                                                                      <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:279px;height:96px;">
                                                                                        <v:fill type="tile" src="http://www.spaceform.com/SF/media/email/trade/giftideas/cell_20.jpg" color="#ffffff" />
                                                                                        <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
                                                                                      <![endif]-->
                                                                                      <div>
                                                                                          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, </div>
                                                                                      <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                                                                                        </v:textbox>
                                                                                      </v:rect>
                                                                                      <![endif]-->
                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                    <td rowspan="3" width="273" height="293"><img src="http://www.spaceform.com/SF/media/email/trade/giftideas/cell_21.jpg" border="0" style="display:block;" width="273" height="293" /></td>
                                                                                  </tr>
                                                                                  <tr>
                                                                                    <td width="279" height="38"><img src="http://www.spaceform.com/SF/media/email/trade/giftideas/cell_22.jpg" border="0" style="display:block;" width="279" height="38" /></td>
                                                                                  </tr>
                                                                                  <tr>
                                                                                    <td width="279" height="159"><img src="http://www.spaceform.com/SF/media/email/trade/giftideas/cell_23.jpg" border="0" style="display:block;" width="279" height="159" /></td>
                                                                                  </tr>
                                                                                  <tr>
                                                                                    <td colspan="2" width="552" height="40"><img src="http://www.spaceform.com/SF/media/email/trade/giftideas/cell_24.jpg" border="0" style="display:block;" width="552" height="40" /></td>
                                                                                  </tr>
                                                                                  <tr>
                                                                                    <td colspan="2" width="279" height="69"><img src="http://www.spaceform.com/SF/media/email/trade/giftideas/cell_25.jpg" border="0" style="display:block;" width="552" height="85">


                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                  </tr>

                                                                                    <td colspan="4" width="600" height="45"><img src="http://www.spaceform.com/SF/media/email/trade/giftideas/cell_26.jpg" border="0" style="display:block;" width="600" height="45" /></td>
                                                                                  </tr>
                                                                                  <tr>
                                                                                    <td colspan="4" width="600" height="324"><img src="http://www.spaceform.com/SF/media/email/trade/giftideas/cell_27.jpg" border="0" style="display:block;" width="600" height="324" /></td>
                                                                                  </tr>
                                                                        </table>
                                                                    <!-- // End Module: Standard Content \\ -->

                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </table>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>                                                
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                            </table>
                                <!-- // End Template Body \\ -->
                                    </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">
                                <!-- // Begin Template Footer \\ -->
                                <table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" width="600" id="templateFooter">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td valign="top" class="footerContent">

                                            <!-- // Begin Module: Standard Footer \\ -->

                                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td colspan="2" valign="middle" id="social" style="padding-bottom:20px">
                                                        <div mc:edit="std_social" style="font-size: 14px; font-style:normal">
                                                            We love being social, 
                                                            why not come and say hi... <a href="http://www.facebook.com/Spaceform"><img src="http://www.spaceform.com/SF/media/site/Newsletters/Email%20Test%20Images/facebook2.png" alt="on Facebook" style="max-width:600px; id="Img9" mc:label="header_image" mc:edit="header_image" mc:allowdesigner mc:allowtext /></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                                        <a href="http://twitter.com/spaceform"><img src="http://www.spaceform.com/SF/media/site/Newsletters/Email%20Test%20Images/twitter2.png" alt="on Twitter" style="max-width:600px; id="Img10" mc:label="header_image" mc:edit="header_image" mc:allowdesigner mc:allowtext /></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                                        <a href="http://www.pinterest.com/spaceform/"><img src="http://www.spaceform.com/SF/media/site/Newsletters/Email%20Test%20Images/pinterest2.png" alt="or on Pinterest" style="max-width:600px; id="Img11" mc:label="header_image" mc:edit="header_image" mc:allowdesigner mc:allowtext /></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                                        </div>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td valign="top" width="350">
                                                        <div mc:edit="std_footer">
                                                            <em>Copyright &copy; *|CURRENT_YEAR|* *|LIST:COMPANY|*, All rights reserved.        >
                                                            <br />
                                                            *|IFNOT:ARCHIVE_PAGE|* *|LIST:DESCRIPTION|*
                                                            <br />
                                                            <strong>Our mailing address is:</strong>
                                                            <br />
                                                            *|HTML:LIST_ADDRESS_HTML|**|END:IF|* 
                                                        </div>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td valign="top" width="190" id="monkeyRewards">
                                                        <div mc:edit="monkeyrewards">
                                                            *|IF:REWARDS|* *|HTML:REWARDS|* *|END:IF|*
                                                        </div>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td colspan="2" valign="middle" id="utility">
                                                        <div mc:edit="std_utility">
                                                            &nbsp;<a href="*|UNSUB|*">unsubscribe from this list</a> | <a href="*|UPDATE_PROFILE|*">update subscription preferences</a><br />
                                                        </div>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                            <!-- // End Module: Standard Footer \\ -->

                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                <!-- // End Template Footer \\ -->
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <br />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </center>
</body>
```

Comment: Please try to reduce the code size to something that could actually be read by a human!

Answer (score 0):

You cant have empty `<td>`, outlook will ignore all styling you have made.
So insert a small transparent image inside them like `<img src="Img/trans.png" height="1" width="1" style="display:block">`

You dont have the `<head>` in the code so i Can see it, but remember you cant style with external css. Gmail removes everything in your header.. So everything needs to be inline styling

EDIT:
After looking a bit more on your code i can see you have lot of `rowspan=""` some mail client dosnt like that. If neede try only to use colspan, and not rowspan. All of the vertical pictures side by side can get ugly.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like when you sliced the image you somehow lost a 16px high by 24px wide chunk off the bottom of each sidebar image.

The sidebar images, cell_02.jpg and cell_04.jpg, are 1474px tall while the center column images add to 1490px tall. The sidebar table cells get stretched vertically to match the height of the center column, leaving 16px of empty space, and center the images vertically, leaving 8px of empty space top and bottom.

I suggest you find the missing bits and make each sidebar image 16px taller. Alternatively, you could take a 16px slice off the bottom of cell_25.jpg, paste it to the top of cell_26.jpg, and fill in the missing corners.